# Specify var type in phpstorm smarty template

Tags: smarty, phpstorm

I have a smarty template .tpl with some $var which is an instance of some Class. In .php files there're phpdoc comments such as /** @var Class $var */.
Is there any way to do the same in .tpl files to make code completion work?

PHPStorm v7.1

thanks

Comment: i wish this was possible too.